# Openvpn client command-line set session time duration

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I want to do something like this using the OpenVPN client on my Ubuntu machine to connect to an OpenVPN server:

Pseudo-command:

```
openvpn --config myconfig.ovpn --session-duration=15m
```

What are the command-line arguments for something like "session-duration"?

Answer (score 0):

I did it the brute force way.

**Start OpenVPN**

```
sudo openvpn --config myconfig.ovpn --daemon
```

**Kill OpenVPN**

```
sudo kill -9 $(ps aux | grep openvpn | grep ^root | awk '{print $2}')
```